# provide more than one processor with taskset

Tags: bash, java, cpu

I am using taskset to assign CPU **cores 4-7** to a java process that normally uses ~200-400% CPU. The cores 4-7 were isolated on boot so only the java process should run on them.

Eventually taskset seems to lock down the spawned java process to one of the four cores rather than assigning it to all cores.

The command I use looks like:

```
taskset -c 4,5,6,7 java [...] -jar [...]
```

Using `taskset -c 4,5,6,7 stress -c 4` behaves the same and uses only one core.

How can I assign all four cores to the java process?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer on my own: It's simply adding the `-a` option which does **as mentioned in the help** (`taskset -h`)

> "operate on all the tasks (threads) for a given pid

So the working command is

```
taskset -cpa 4-7 $(pgrep -n java)
```

`pgrep` is used here to get the PID of the latest started java process.

I hope this answer might help somebody who tries to assign multiple CPU cores to one process and all its threads without the use of complex containers systems or VM's.